# get index from postgresql sequence using liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

What attribute of `column` I should use in order to get index value from postgresql `sequence`? `valueNumeric`? `valueComputed`?

As far as I understand the value of attribute should be `nextval( 'simple_id_seq' )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In postgresql sequence values are created as INTEGER or BIGINT.

Often this was done by using SERIAL or BIGSERIAL as column type ... but will indirectly create a sequencer of int or bigint and set the default value of the column to nextval(sequencer).

In a resultset of table data the column contains int or bigint.

Normaly there is no need to use nextval(sequencer) ... it fills the column on INSERT automatically (in the INSERT statemant the column shoult not appear).

Refer to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use SERIAL or BIGSERIAL as suggested by @double_word_distruptor, use valueComputed.

With valueComputed you are telling Liquibase you are passing a function like nextval('simple_id_seq') and it will not try to parse it as a number or do any quoting.

You may also be able to use valueSequenceNext="simple_id_seq" to gain a little cross-database compatibility.